# Class conflict on active via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I designed a HTML site and put `active` class on `a`

```
$('a').click(function(){
     $('a').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

It's working. And I have a menu structure and connection footer and top menu on `active`.

```
 $('.menuHolder li a').click(function (e) {
      $('.menuHolder li a').removeClass('active');
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      $('a[href="' + link + '"]').addClass('active');

    });
```

Now, when i click menu-item get `active` class, OK. But when i click a item on menu, remove `active` class on my menu-item.

So, i want menu-item `active` remove only click another menu-item. How can i fix it?

Comment: Are there more `a` elements with the same `href` attribute? Because if not, you can just do `$(this).addClass('active');`. Unfortunately I don't understand your actual problem.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Create http://jsfiddle.net/ of it.

Comment: Or at least show the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: Works for me : http://jsbin.com/ufokuq/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry.

When i this code, everything is normal. Maybe, every `a` add and remove active automatic now.

```
$('a').click(function(){
     $('a').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.menuHolder li a').click(function (e) {
      $('.menuHolder li a.active').removeClass('active');
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      $('a[href="' + link + '"]').addClass('active');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign specific class to your menu-item and use toggle instead:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
$('.menuHolder li a').removeClass('active');
```

to a

```
$('.menuHolder li a.active').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKZ2a/)

```
    $(function(){
        $('.menuHolder li a').click(function (e) {
              $('.menuHolder li a').removeClass('active');
              $(this).addClass('active');

        }); 
    });
```